# Acessar página em outro projeto

Tags: java, jsf

Estou um desenvolvendo um sistema que está divido em três módulos (Projetos distintos), usando Framework JSF (Java Server Faces).

Eu tenho um módulo principal que possui uma tela de login, que por sua vez tem um controle de acesso via filtro. A ideia é que quando o usuário realizar o login e acessar a página home, então ele poderá chamar outras páginas que estão em outros módulos.

Não obtive sucesso ao solicitar uma página em outro projeto, estou tendo problemas principalmente com o Filtro.

Será que alguém poderia me dar alguma ideia de como acessar outra página de outro projeto?

Segue o código do meu filtro abaixo:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) resp;
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();

    String loginURI = request.getContextPath() + "/RESOURCES/paginas/login.xhtml";

    boolean loggedIn = session != null && session.getAttribute("user") != null;
    boolean loginRequest = request.getRequestURI().equals(loginURI);
    boolean resourceRequest = request.getRequestURI()
            .startsWith(request.getContextPath() + ResourceHandler.RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER);

    boolean resourceRequestCSS = request.getRequestURI().contains("/RESOURCES/css");
    boolean resourceRequestIcons = request.getRequestURI().contains("/RESOURCES/icons");
    boolean resourceRequestImages = request.getRequestURI().contains("/RESOURCES/images");

    if (loggedIn || loginRequest || resourceRequest || resourceRequestCSS || resourceRequestIcons
            || resourceRequestImages) {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);

    } else {
        response.sendRedirect(loginURI);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia gerar um token (salvo em banco de dados compartilhado - ou outra forma forma de intercomunicação) no aplicativo **chamador** e envia-lo (token) na requisição ao aplicativo **chamado**, que por sua vez através do filtro  verificara no banco compartilhado e autorizaria ou não o acesso ao aplicativo **chamado**.

Espero ter ajudado...

Comment: Eu retirei o **Filtro** e consegui enxergar as páginas nos outros projetos, mas foi apenas um teste. Preciso muito do filtro, lembrando que o filtro só enxerga apenas o projeto em que está situado. Não descartei sua ideia, pois quando consegui algo comento aqui.

Obrigado por enquanto